# Adding offset to x y axes in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am writing a view in django which sends pdf file as a response. Pdf has a line graph of values against dates done using matplotlib.The graph looks very similar to this [image: one] .

If i have the max y-data point as 1000, then the graph touches top x axis which i do not want.For example see this figure.

[image].

At (3.0,4.0) line graph touches top x-axis.

I want to give some extra space to yaxis(i.e increase max-y reading to 1100) so that my graph looks good, as shown in first image.

How would i do that?

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import FigureCanvasPdf
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
r_name  = request.GET.get('r_name')      
index_id = request.GET.get('index_id')
resp = api_views.historical_observations(request,index_id)      
data = resp.data.get('data')    
x,y=[],[] 
for datam in data:
    x.append(datam.get('measurement_date'))
    y.append(datam.get('value'))        
fig=Figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)   
ax.set_title(r_name)
ax.plot_date(x, y, '-bo')    
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))    
fig.autofmt_xdate()
canvas=FigureCanvasPdf(fig)
response= HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
filename = settings.PDF_FILE_PREFIX+"_"+r_name+"_"+request.GET.get('start_date')+"_" +\
            request.GET.get('end_date')+".pdf"
response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename="+filename
canvas.print_pdf(response)
return response
```

Comment: simply setting the y-axis range to something bigger should be enough?

Comment: @M4rtini i think i can do that by calculating max and min of y values.But i liked the idea of `offset` from jqplot http://www.jqplot.com/ .I would like to know whether it is possible with matploblib?

Comment: I'm not familiar with jqplot so i can't comment on that. An alternative to setting the y-axis range, is defining a margin for the axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try either:
`ax.set_ymargin(0.1)` (accepts float from 0 to 1)
or
`ax.set_ylim([min(y)-1, max(Y)+1])`

Change the 1 to something that makes the plot look good. It would depend on the scale of what you're plotting. For ylim you could do percentage adjustments by multiplying by 0.9 \ 1.1

Comment: first one do not have any effect on the graph.second gives me this error `'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'ylim'`

Comment: Hmm, try set_ylim instead

Comment: And ymargin was a function not a property. Try the edit i made.

Comment: second one works,thanks for the answer. Please remove first ans. It giving me error.

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy - `ax.margins` or `ax.set_ymargin`, etc are the standard way to do this in matplotlib.  What error are you getting?

Comment: @JoeKington He was getting errors because i had written ymargin instead of set_ymargin at first. That's my assumption atleast.